# Help identifying a card game with 8 or more decks

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember playing this game as a child (3 decades back) with my grandparents. This was played with 4 or more players (usually even number of players). These two teams are then supposed to race to 10,000 points on a scale.

Each player starts with 16 cards (can be 20 or more as well if there are less number of players). The objective of the game is to play a hand, the team that wins the hand can then disclose different combination of cards to score the points. If the stack of cards finishes, then you gather all the cards and start over until on team reaches 10,000 points. The interesting part is that every repeat combination during the same round nets you higher points. Some of the combinations are as follows -

1. Club Queen + Diamond Jack (1st pair - 40, 2nd pair - 500, 3rd pair - 750, 1000, 1250, etc)
2. Spade Queen + Heart Jack (1st pair - 40, 2nd pair - 500, 3rd pair - 750, 1000, 1250, etc)
3. A+K+Q+J+10 of the selected suit (250,1000,1250,2000, etc)
4. K+Q of any color - 20 (this doesn't scale with repeat combinations)
5. K+Q of the selected suit - 40 (this doesn't scale either)

In our house we used to call this game "Basic". However when I search for this game online, I do not find any useful link. Has anyone heard of this game, can you point me to any reference?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds a lot like Pinochle. Maybe it's a variant?

https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/pinochle-2

Comment: If you explain which aspects of pinochle match (and which don't), your answer would be better.